# powershell 2 event handling

Tags: events, powershell

I want to handle the System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon's BalloonTipClicked. That is to say, I want to handle the event when the tip is clicked. My code is below, however I can't catch the event. Please help !

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Timers")

## This is the location of your download files
$notification = "E:\TDdownload"

$notification = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon 

$notification.Icon = "C:\Users\Sefler\Desktop\PerfCenterCpl.ico"
$notification.BalloonTipIcon = "Info" 
$notification.BalloonTipText = "Windows will now try to clean "+ $fileLocation +" as scheduled." 
$notification.BalloonTipTitle = "Windows auto maintaince"

$notification.Visible = $True 
$notification.ShowBalloonTip(15000)

## Register a click event
register-objectevent $notification BalloonTipClicked -sourceIdentifier notification_event

## Wait for the onClick event
wait-event -timeout 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'm with you now. This works from within ISE:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Timers")

## This is the location of your download files 
$notification = "E:\TDdownload" 

$notification = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon

$notification.Icon = "C:\Users\Sefler\Desktop\PerfCenterCpl.ico"
$notification.BalloonTipTitle = "Windows auto maintaince"
$notification.BalloonTipIcon = "Info"
$title = "Windows will now try to clean {0} as scheduled." -f $fileLocation
$notification.BalloonTipText = $title
$notification.Visible = $True
## Clear any previous events
Remove-Event notification_event -ea SilentlyContinue
## Register a click event
register-objectevent $notification BalloonTipClicked notification_event 
$notification.ShowBalloonTip(15000) 

## Wait for the onClick event 
wait-event -timeout 15 -sourceIdentifier notification_event > $null
Remove-Event notification_event -ea SilentlyContinue

"Done!!"

Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier notification_event
```

Note this works when you click in the body of the window but *not* when you click the "x" to close the window.  So you may want to subscribe to the BalloonTipClosed event also (or instead of BalloonTipClicked).

Comment: I've refered that, but the question is it can't catch the event. As my code shows, once the even occurs, the script will NOT wait 15 seconds. But I script always wait for 15 seconds.

Comment: It drives me crazy!!!!! When I try to run your vesion and mine in PowerShell ISE. Both works!! However, when I run them in normal PowerShell window, none of them works! I've tried them in two computers. One is Windows 7 Pro and the other is Vista Home Basic. I just can't understand why!

Comment: Try starting your Powershell.exe with the option -STA.

Comment: FYI, ISE, since it is a GUI app, uses single-threaded apartment (STA) by default whereas the console host uses multi-threaded apartment (MTA) by default unless you specify -STA when starting PowerShell.exe.