# Properly displaying a tray balloon tooltip in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, notifications, system-tray

**Short version**: I think I need help with properly using events in PowerShell that are invoked as a result of a Windows Message to get rid of a balloon tooltip's icon.

**Long Version**:

I have a long-running PowerShell command (a build) that I would like to be notified when it completes via a balloon tooltip in the system tray/notification area.

I was able to create a Write-BalloonTip script (below) that does roughly what I want. The only problem is that, [as sometimes happens with tray icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067844/issue-with-notifyicon-not-dissappearing-on-winforms-app), the tray icon doesn't disappear until I mouse over it. By re-using the same global variable to represent the [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx), I'm able to re-use this script and keep it so that only one system tray icon remains (until I mouse over it). This still feels like a hack. I tried to add an event handler so that it'd be notified on the [BalloonTipClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.balloontipclosed.aspx) event and then dispose of it there. In the event handler, I tried all three techniques I've seen suggested for getting rid of the lingering icon to no avail.

The annoying part is that a simple `.Dispose` seems to work on subsequent calls of the script, leading me to think that the event script block isn't being called at all.

I've verified that BalloonTipClosed gets called after the tip fades away in a separate WinForms app.

Am I missing something basic? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the code for "Write-BalloonTip.ps1":

```
param
(
    $text,
    $title = "",
    $icon = "Info",
    $timeout=15000
)

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | out-null

if ($global:writeBalloonTipIcon)
{
    # This gets rid of the previous one
    $global:writeBalloonTipIcon.Dispose()
}

$global:writeBalloonTipIcon = new-object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon 
$global:writeBalloonTipIcon.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information

# FIXME: This *should* cleanup the icon after it's done, but it doesn't seem to work
$global:writeBalloonTipIcon.add_BalloonTipClosed(
  {
    # this *should* work, but it's not. What am I missing?
    $global:writeBalloonTipIcon.Icon = $null; 
    $global:writeBalloonTipIcon.Visible = $false; 
    $global:writeBalloonTipIcon.Dispose();
  });

$global:writeBalloonTipIcon.Visible = $true;
$global:writeBalloonTipIcon.ShowBalloonTip($timeout, $title, $text, $icon);
```

Comment: Maybe a little bit offtopic, but I found very useful Growl for Windows. Jaykul wrote a library that wraps the functionality. There is also a plugin that notifies you when your build/rebuild finishes. You may find it here: http://huddledmasses.org/more-growl-for-windows-from-powershell/ (I don't know if it is the latest version)

Comment: Not really, there wasn't a quick fix, so we just keep recycling a single global icon. It's a reasonable workaround until we get motivated to actually fix it by handling the STA issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to execute this code in an STA thread. PowerShell (v2 shown here) executes in an MTA thread by default:

```
PS U:\> [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread


ManagedThreadId    : 5
ExecutionContext   : System.Threading.ExecutionContext
Priority           : Normal
IsAlive            : True
IsThreadPoolThread : False
IsBackground       : False
ThreadState        : Running
ApartmentState     : MTA
CurrentUICulture   : en-US
CurrentCulture     : en-US
Name               : Pipeline Execution Thread
```

Comment: I think this is getting closer to the core of the problem as it seems the notification event is being sent via a Windows message. Any ideas of how to do this the right way? It seems that an Invoke-Apartment should work, but I can't quite get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the Register-ObjectEvent to subscribe to the BalloonTipClosed event.  This came up recently in [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118093/powershell-2-event-handling).  Check it out.

Comment: I think the core of the problem is the STA issue because the event isn't being raised unless it's on a STA thread.

Comment: The JIT Debugger reports "System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: There is no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread. You can provide one in the DefaultRunspace property of the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace type" on the BallonTipClosed event so the event is being raised. You can make a Runspace in PS but it's significantly quicker to use the Register-ObjectEvent